# Question about the local maxima of a funciton

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functions

Assume $f(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)$ is a smooth, continuos, differentiable function, and let we want to check if $(x'_1,x'_2,\dots,x'_n)$ is the local maxima or not.

Assume the first order condition is satisfied i.e. $\nabla f(x'_1,x'_2,\dots,x'_n)=0$, however the corresponding Hessian matrix $\nabla \nabla f(x'_1,x'_2,\dots,x'_n)$ is negative semi-definite and all higher order derivatives are $\boldsymbol{0}$ matrix. In this case, can we say $x'_1,x'_2,\dots,x'_n$ is a local maxima of function $f$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $f$ is smooth, we may apply the [Taylor formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#Taylor_series_in_several_variables).
This guarantees the existence of $\delta > 0 $ such that for every $y=(y_1,\ldots,y_n) \in B(x',\delta) \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ (where $x' = (x_1',\ldots,x_n')$ and $B(x',\delta)$ is the open ball centered in $x'$), holds
$$ f(y) = f(x')+\nabla f(x')^T(y-x')+\frac{1}{2}(y-x')^T\nabla^2f(x)(y-x')$$
where I have used the fact that

> all higher order derivatives are $\mathbf{0}$ matrix.

Since $\nabla^2f(x')$ is negative semi-definite, we must have $(y-x')^T\nabla^2f(x')(y-x') \leq 0$. Finally using $\nabla f(x') = 0$ we get
$$f(y)-f(x') = (y-x')^T\nabla^2f(x')(y-x') \leq 0.$$
It follows that $f(y) \leq f(x')$ for every $y\in B(x',\delta)$, i.e. $f(x')$ is a local maximum.